# How to fill my html with json object?

Tags: ajax

I am new in ajax.
I am trying to get value and want to fill in html code snippet.
I have html code and json object that has value.
Now I want to show the specific value in the different-different part of html code.
Here is my html code:-

```
<div>
<div class="borb clearfix">
    <div class="profileholder fleft">
        <img src="images/users/1.png" class="userpic">
        <div class="icon state green"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="remainder">
        <div class="padl10">
            <div class="username">Anurag Shivpuri</div>
            <div class="desig">Cheif Information Officer</div>
            <div class="loc">Credit Operation  |  Pune</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="userdata">
    <li>
        <span class="lbl">Employee Code :</span>
        <span> 2007</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="lbl">Role_Designation :</span>
        <span> Senior HR</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="lbl">Department :</span>
        <span> HR</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="lbl">Sub_Department :</span>
        <span> Talent Acquisition</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="lbl">Official E-mail Id :</span>
        <span> atul.gupta@bajajfinserve.co.in</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="lbl">Mobile No :</span>
        <span> 9844333932</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="footbar">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Reward</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Incentive</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Movement</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Leaves</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">LnD</a>
</div>
```

On success of ajax I am getting the value now I want to fill it in my html code.
Please help me.

Comment: can you show the json response and mention where exactly you want to fill

Comment: what research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library (like knockout) to do that, or you can use jQuery to create the elements:

`$("<div>").append("some text").appendTo("body"); //creates a div, append some text and...`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a success event in your ajax, you could grab an empty DOM element and set its content.

```
document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = jsonData.myProperty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use innerHTML in javascript.

Set some ID on the element you need to update:

```
<li>
    <span class="lbl">Employee Code :</span>
    <span id='employeeCode'> 2007</span>
</li>
```

Then update it with your json value:

```
document.getElementById('employeeCode').innerHTML= yourJsonObject.employeeCodeValue;
```